# How to show Internet Explorer's History in a control?

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, browser-history

I just got a requirement to emmbed an IE control into a form, and the user wants to get access to all the browser histories.

I think the history manager in IE will do this, so how can I emmbed the history manager into my control?

Or can I read the history information, put it in a ListView and handle it myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the following CodeProject article:

**The tiny wrapper class for URL history interface in C#**
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ponta.aspx

This article describes what the UrlHistoryWrapper class is and how to use it. The UrlHistoryWrapper class is a tiny class that wraps the C# equivalence of the IURLHistory interface in the MSDN document. They are wrapped into easy to use C# classes. This class provides the following features.

1. Enumerate the items in the history
   cache.
2. Place the specified URL into the
   history. If the URL does not exist
   in the history, an entry is created
   in the history. If the URL does
   exist in the history, it is
   overwritten.
3. Clears history on a per-user basis.
4. Queries the history and reports
   whether a particular URL has been
   visited by the current user.