# Storing The Contents Of A AutoCompleteSource (HistoryList) In a String

Tags: c#, string, autocomplete, browser-history, autocompletebox

All I am simply trying to do is display the AutoCompleteSource.HistoryList in a message box. All the following code does is display the words HistoryList. How can I make it actually show the URLS of the HistoryLIst, in other words I want the contents of the HistoryList to appear in the MessageBox.

```
  var s = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, toolStripTextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.OfType<string>());
    MessageBox.Show(s, "History", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Answer (score 0):

AutoCompleteSource is an enumeration that describes where the auto-complete values come from. Your variable 's' is thus the string representation of the AutoCompleteSource.HistoryList enumeration value and probably not what you were looking for.

AutoCompleteCustomSource is the collection of auto-complete strings and is more likely what you're looking for although it only shows the manually entered auto-complete values e.g. if you set your AutoCompleteSource enumeration to FileSystem, it won't contain the available FileSystem auto-complete values (only the ones you've entered manually in the Designer or code-behind).

Further to this, AutoCompleteStringCollection is a collection and in order to retrieve all of the values you will need to use code similar to that shown below.

```
var s = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, something.AutoCompleteCustomSource.OfType<string>());
MessageBox.Show(s, "History", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

If you're trying to get the actual list of items in the URL history, the articles below might be more useful.

- [How do I get the Internet Explorer download history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133281/how-do-i-get-the-internet-explorer-download-history)
- http://hardcodedblog.blogspot.co.nz/2009/10/obtaining-browser-visited-url-history.html

Comment: Would I type something like this   s.Join(Environment.NewLine, AllURL.AutoCompleteCustomSource.OfType<string>());

Comment: Are you saying that this is impossible?

Comment: @Alex Johnson, I updated my comment to clarify the assignment to 's'. If you goal is to loop through the list of URL history items programatically, then AutoCompleteSource is probably not going to help you. I've added links to a couple of related articles that will help however.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but this must be wrong or something.

    var s = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, HistoryList.AutoCompleteCustomSource.OfType<string>());
            MessageBox.Show(s, "History", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

HistoryList doesn't exist in current context.  The articles though that you gave are about how to find history of  a different browser.  I am trying to create a history function for my own browser.  Thanks.

Comment: In your case (based purely on the comments above) the code would be AllURL.AutoCompleteCustomSource.OfType<string>()... Presumably you have a TextBox or ComboBox you want to put the auto-completed values in - whatever that control is called, that's the thing you should be accessing the AutoCompleteCustomSource property of.

Comment: var s = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, toolStripTextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.OfType<string>());
           
            MessageBox.Show(s, "History", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

That is my code above but the message box doesn't show anything unfortunately.

Comment: @Alex Johnson, the AutoCompleteCustomSource will only show the entries you added to the collection yourself. If you update your question with the code you're using to Add() items to the AutoCompleteCustomSource collection, I might be able to help.